# PictureBox and ImageList small pictures problem

Tags: c#

I need to show a picture from a different imageList in a few pictureBox, but the pictures are so small and I can't find a way to solve that.

I've tried with the options of streched, zoom, centerImage, autoSize but none of them work.

This is what it looks like when I start the program.
The three images are streched, autosized, and centered and it's always that small.

[image]

The code I've used is only the simple one to show the first photo of the imageList:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Halkidiki1.Images[0];
pictureBox2.Image = Halkidiki2.Images[0];
pictureBox3.Image = Halkidiki3.Images[0];
```

Comment: what about the size?

Comment: i tried changing the size via propreties but it says that can be only from 0 to 256, and cant make it to 295 like the pictureBox. If thats what you meant.

Comment: Maybe the images __are__ too small. Or you didn't change the IamgeList to its maximum image size of 256*256 pixels. And its color depth..?? if you make it 256xsomething it should look a lot better in a 295 width pbox.. Do note that all images in an imagelist will share the same properties! - For even larger images you need to load a List<Bitmap>.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with combination of “SizeMode” setting to stretch and “ClientSize” to the size the you wish?

Comment: i tried changing the size via propreties but it says that can be only from 0 to 256, and cant make it to 295 like the pictureBox. If thats what you meant.

Comment: pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage ;
   
   pictureBox1.ClientSize = new Size(xSize, ySize);